# akka actors - Implementing workflows, activities or dialogs

Tags: dialog, workflow, akka, actor

Let's say I want to implement ProgrammableRemote in akka -

```
   ProgrammableRemote

    - WatchMovie
          1. Tv ! PowerOn
          1.1 Tv ! ChangeInput 3
          2. DVD ! PowerOn
          3. AVReceiver ! PowerOn
          3.1 AVReceiver ! SetInput 'DVD'
```

I could use futures to sequence 1 and 1.1 (and 3. and 3.1). However, that will cause 1.1 to run on a separate thread from the actor's receive thread. If I use 'pipeTo self', I will need to handle case for 'PowerOn completed' message from TV in the 'receive' method.

Ideally, I would like to be able to extend an actor's receive to deal with replies from other actors dynamically based on outstanding requests. Is there any solution in akka for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just send the messages, their ordering is retained per sender, so if you get a ChangeInput before it is powered on, you'll need to deal with that anyway. Use "become" or the Akka FSM DSL to encode the different states and which commands are possible within each state.

Comment: Your suggestion is more relevant for implementing the 'Tv' actor itself. To implement the ProgrammableRemoteActor, I still have to find a way to wait for TV to power on before I send 'ChangeInput' message. This is important as the 'Tv' could be actual device and hence the message could lost if sent if the TV is not completely powered on. I guess, 'become' will still help. But seems like this pattern is very common for request/response still interactions and deserves a first-class syntax.

Comment: That's not true imho, since someone else could turn the TV off the nanosecond after the TV is turned on. I'd just send the two messages, in the real world the remote control has no idea whether the signal worked or not.

Comment: For keeping a conversational context, it is very useful to just spawn a child actor that will deal with that. See "Saga" in CQRS terminology

Comment: I guess the Tv and remotecontrol analogy only goes so far. However, it is clear that we could have a situation where in we wait for response for the first outgoing request before sending the next one (for example, the second message may get influenced by the response from the first one).<br> I could do: become { case response => ... } orElse mainReceive. This will work when we have only request outstanding. What if I want to be able to send multiple requests to various actors concurrently and only wait for them when I need to use the results.

Comment: You essentially have 3 options: 1) have an identified for the flow and keep a Map of open conversations. 2) Create a child for every conversation. or 3) Use ask & Futures. One could imagine some sort of DSL that spawns the child actor and deals with the tricky bits while providing a declarative way of dealing with the flow of information.

Comment: I will write to hash out the three options in separate comments.

Comment: Use of identifier with map for open conversations will not be very transparent. Having a child actor for each conversation should work - but again not very transparent.
Use of futures:
However, what I want is to be able to write sequential code on the surface but take advantage of asynchronous nature of actor model transparently.
fv1 = a1.req1(p1, …)
fv2 = a2.req2(p11,…)
and so on.
Now when I do some computation that requires values returned by fv1 and fv2,
  v3 = some expression (fv1, fv2)
It should transparently suspend the actor thread till fv1 is available and fv2 is available.

Comment: If the expression involves mostly computation (no IO) we can solve it by doing receive on each of the future's channel. However, the expression might involve requests to other actors. To achieve maximum IO concurrency we want to have as many outstanding requests as possible. The challenge here is to be able to execute those part of the expressions that are ready and as responses come from the actors evaluate the expression. AFAIK futures can be modeled as monads - but then that forces a sequential order of evaluation.

Comment: Some people claim that actor model represents true OO - it faithfully models the encapsulation and message passing. However, if we trying to convert an existing OO application into a fully actor model we will have to model each method call as a message and the return value as 'future'. This will require blocking after each message send which actor model discourages as it might lead to deadlock. If we avoid blocking then we need to write the application to deal with the asynchronous nature of the actor model.

Comment: Ideally we should be able to take an existing OO application and transparently convert it into an actor model (say, by clever use of dynamic proxies and AOP) and remove the use of locks and other synchronization primitives.

Comment: No, you cannot convert OO to actor-based trivially because OO tries to trick you into thinking that reads are cheap, which they are not in a distributed system.

Comment: And by "OO" I mean "The way Java, .NET, C++" defines OO.

Comment: I do understand that the conversion from the traditional OO style code to actor model is non-trivial. What I am trying to see is this even possible (computation model wise)? Whether it will be practical or not (performance wise) is a different issue. For example, caching proxy actor can maintain the illusion of cheap reads.

Comment: [Concurrent Object-Oriented Programming in Act 1](http://web.media.mit.edu/~lieber/Lieberary/OOP/Act-1/Concurrent-OOP-in-Act-1.html)

Comment: TypeActor does help but I think the issue is still dealing with multiple outstanding futures. Act 1's interpreter can evaluate function arguments in parallel and only block on them when needed. This is what I was talking about. In Lisp/Scheme it is easy to change evaluation scheme (lazy, eager, future based, etc.) with a minimal change in the interpreter. Not sure about Scala.

Comment: Well, you are free to use whatever language you want.